# Unity general close button C#

Tags: c#, android, ios, unity-game-engine

I'm writing a C# code in Unity 5.3.4. I've been trying to develop a button that will close the app be it when I test it on my computer or when I'm in Android or iOS.

For android I've found this code and it's working:

```
if (Application.platform == RuntimePlatform.Android) {
        if (Input.GetKeyUp(KeyCode.Escape)) {
            //quit application on return button
            Application.Quit(); 
            return;
        }
}
```

This exits the code if you press the return button. I've develop a function that gets called when you press the exit button and it calls Application.Quit(). The problem is that this does nothing when I'm testing the code in my computer.

Is there a more generic way of closing an APP in unity, independently of the platform where you run the APP?

Comment: Do you mean in editor? Or your exe build not closing.

Comment: @SP. I'm in the editor, in play mode.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `UnityEditor.EditorApplication.isPlaying = false;` for stopping game in editor.

Use `System.Diagnostics.Process.GetCurrentProcess().Kill();` if you even want to quit Unity as well as the app in all devices.

But `Application.Quit ()` works on most devices without issue. It's not an editor method to call.

Answer (score 3):

You should never have a quit button in your mobile app(Anroid or iOS). That's the function of the home button.

Now that you understand that, `Application.Quit();`  is ignored in the **Editor**. You set `UnityEditor.EditorApplication.isPlaying` to `false` to exit game in the **Editor**. With the help of Preprocessor Directives, you can make an exit function that will work on both Editor and standalone builds.

```
void Quit()
{
    #if UNITY_EDITOR
    UnityEditor.EditorApplication.isPlaying = false;
    #else
    Application.Quit();
    #endif
}
```

**EDIT**:

You **MUST** put `UnityEditor.EditorApplication.isPlaying = false;` in  `#if UNITY_EDITOR`, like I did in the `Quit()` function above or your App won't build later on.

Unity will throw *The name `UnityEditor' does not exist in the current context* error message.

Comment: On android you should use the back button to close the app. ([android back button](http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/25535/android-back-button-event.html))

Comment: @ColmanJ Yes, you should. You can even set `Input.backButtonLeavesApp = true;` and that will automatically quit the app on back button press. This works on Android and Windows phone. On iOS, the home button should do its work fine without any code. TBH, I thought OP had a UI button he's using to exit the app which is something I said he should never do.

Comment: @Programmer What if in IOS,  I am using another app to open unity app to view AR, after use I need to close the unity app and go back to the primary app.Any suggestion?